# Griddb NodeJs Driver not filtering on boolean type column

Tags: griddb

Hi I have a table that has a collection of local times across varying timezones. I'm trying to get a count of the timezones with daylight savings time currently.

But before getting to that aspect, I'm having trouble filtering on the boolean field with the node api to just get all time zone that has day light savings. When I try to run this query I get the below error saying it can't find a column called "true".

`time_in_zone.query("SELECT * where dstActive = true")`

`[150012:TQ_COLUMN_NOT_FOUND] No such column true`

However the same query will work from the client just fine. Am I missing something?

Query in the gs_client

```
gs[public]> sql select * from Time_In_Zone where dstActive = true;
25 results. (2 ms)
gs[public]> get 1
dateTime,timeZone,dstActive
2024-01-28T15:46:43.603Z,Australia/Yancowinna,true
The 1 results had been acquired.
```